# 419 Error when attempting to post to my controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

I've been trying to submit a post request with axios to my projects controller and I keep getting an error 419(unknown status). Even though I'm passing the CSRF through headers to the controller. When I go into my network tab after posting it says:

```
X-CSRF-TOKEN: undefined
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

However, when I console.log(window.csrf_token) it returns a token.

This is included in my layout.blade.php

```php
<script type="text/javascript">      
    window.csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}"
</script>
```

I define the headers in my app.js for vue:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.csrf_token,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
};
```

and in my projects.vue here is my axios post request:

```js
Swal.queue([{
title: 'Add a New Project?',
input: 'text',
inputAttributes: {
    autocapitalize: 'on'
},
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonText: 'Create Project',
showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
preConfirm: (result) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (result) {
            console.log(result)
            axios.post('/api/projects', {title:result})
            .then(function(response){
                Swal.insertQueueStep({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Your project has been created!'
                })
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                Swal.insertQueueStep({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Something went wrong.'
                })
                console.log(error);
                reject();
            })
        }
    });
}
}])
```

aswell as the store method in ProjectsController.php

```php
    public function store()
    {
        $validated = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);

        Project::create($validated);

        return response()->json($validated);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you are setting the CSRF token in your layout file after the usage hence the reason of getting undefined.

Try using the default way, which is by putting a `meta` tag in your `head` of the main template like this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then to use it you may open the given `bootstrap.js` file where this code is already set:

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Or if this does not exist, put it in your `app.js` script or whichever you use on every page.